# RSelenium passing profile/extraCapabilities to server

Tags: r, firefox, rselenium

My download code stopped working as my code stopped passing "extraCapabilities" properly.

This is what used to work:

```
require(RSelenium)
require(XML)
require(data.table)
source(file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "examples/serverUtils/checkForServer.r"))
source(file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "examples/serverUtils/startServer.r"))
checkForServer(); 
server<-startServer()

referencedirectory <- "d://temp"
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = referencedirectory,  browser.download.folderList = 2L, browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE,
    browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk="text/xml",browser.tabs.remote.autostart = FALSE,browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2 = FALSE,browser.tabs.remote.desktopbehavior = FALSE))

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "firefox",extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open()
```

Now it throws an error:

```
Selenium message:Profile has been set on both the capabilities and these options, but they're different. Unable to determine which one you want to use.

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I have tried an alternative:

```
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser = "firefox", version = "latest", geckover = "0.15.0", iedrver = NULL, phantomver = "2.1.1",
  verbose = TRUE, check = TRUE, extraCapabilities = fprof)
```

That produces the same error in addition to complaining (these complaints do not result in an error by themselves):

```
Selenium message:wrong number of arguments
```

If extraCapabilities are removed, the above code executes, but if you then try:

```
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4446L, browser = "firefox", version = "latest", geckover = "0.15.0", iedrver = NULL, phantomver = "2.1.1",
  verbose = TRUE, check = TRUE)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = "D:/temp"))
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open()
```

You get the same error after the last line. rsDriver opens a browser, but that browser does not have any of the desired properties. If you close the browser (without closing the server) before trying to assign remDr and open it, you will still get the same error.

I have tried version 13, 14, and 15 of the driver and the Server 3.1.0, with the same result.

I have found the line in Java that is throwing the error, but I cannot figure out how to pass a different Firefox profile than the one that gets automatically generated behind the scenes. I have tried various versions of "Profile"/"requiredProfile"/"FirefoxProfile ", etc., but that does not get recognized as a valid input... I also see some discussion of how it may be done in Java, but not in R.

The code used to work for me until about 36 hours ago, and I have been trying to find the way out of it ever since. I am now at complete loss.

UPDATE: the setup with very sensitive about combination of versions. The brand new Selenium server version (3.3.1) works with Gecko 0.15.0 and Firefox 52. Some other combinations may work, but most do not.

Also, when setting the folder location string you need to be careful. In most contexts within R, the forward slash, `/` is OS-neutral, as such, I use it most of the time both in UNIX and Windows. However, when setting `browser.download.dir` in Windows, one apparently has to use the (escaped) backslash, `\\`. Otherwise the directory assignment will appear to work, but it does not work de facto.

Finally, the recommended approach with `rsDriver` works AND the approach with the defunct functions also works again (`checkForServer()` and `startServer`). Lesson to be learned: do not be unlucky like me in choosing the moment to update your Selenium code

Comment: Looks like an issue with selenium https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3632 and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3633

Comment: Give [`splashr`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr) a try

Comment: I have read through the intro page of the package. It is hard to see how I would implement file downloads using this tool. Do you have a specific workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with geckodriver(0.15.0)/selenium(3.3.0). I used the following:

```
library(RSelenium)
referencedirectory <- "c://temp"
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = referencedirectory,  browser.download.folderList = 2L, browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE,
                                 browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk="text/xml",browser.tabs.remote.autostart = FALSE,browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2 = FALSE,browser.tabs.remote.desktopbehavior = FALSE))
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser = "firefox", version = "3.1.0", geckover = "0.14.0", iedrver = NULL, phantomver = "2.1.1",
               verbose = TRUE, check = TRUE, extraCapabilities = fprof)
```

which appeared to function correctly. As noted in the documentation I would advise if possible to use a Docker image to run a Selenium Server which will prevent issues with incompatible browser/driver versions.

Update:

There is an updated version of selenium server which should now address this issue:

```
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser = "firefox", version = "3.3.1", geckover = "0.15.0",
               verbose = TRUE, check = TRUE, extraCapabilities = fprof)
```

Comment: I have copied and pasted your code. Got the same error as before. I cannot use Docker installer as I do not use Windows 10. I have tried the Toolbox (I think it is called) and the installation was not successful. I was getting errors when trying to use it (start the server on one PC and even install it on the other). I have activated virtualization in BIOSes of both

Comment: Yes firefox has been updated. I was running the previous version. There will be a Selenium server version 3.3.1 https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-3.3.1 which should address the problem which should be released shortly.

Comment: Is it possible to affect what gets put into "`moz:profile`" of the server, when calling rsDriver?

Comment: Which version of Firefox would  you recommend for testing in the meantime?

Comment: Selenium Server 3.3.1 is now uploaded on the repository so this should address the issue.

Comment: Indeed, jdharrison, the combination of Firefox 52, Gecko 0.15.0 and Server 3.3.1 works (almost) correctly. I have been testing it now and I do not get files to be saved in the correct folder. When accessing `about:config`, `browser.download.folderList` and `browser.download.dir` are assigned as in `fprof`, but downloads go into default download folder of the standard Firefox. What other options am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you don't really need to makefireprof.
the code is indeed very simple:

```
remDr=rsDriver(browser=browserName,extraCapabilities=list(acceptInsecureCerts=TRUE,acceptUntrustedCerts=TRUE))
```